# Where can I get Heathrow Airport passenger check-in times data and/or lounge entry data?

Tags: public-transport, airports, flight-data

I want to find out the average time between Passenger Airport check-in and their corresponding Lounge entry, to get an idea of the time spent between these two events.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I'm not even sure this consolidated data is available for all of Heathrow. Check-in counters and lounges are operated by a variety of different companies, probably using a variety of different systems. And of course, as the number of people actually using check-in counters (or kiosks) is getting lower, and the number of people using lounges is low, the number of people doing both must be really low. It would help if you explained why you are looking for this data as there may be alternative sources of information which could possibly be easier to get and/or more useful or representative.

Comment: Also, my guess is that the average is probably not very representative, as it must vary quite a lot depending on the type of flight (short or long haul) and the time of day, possibly even the day of the week or the period of the year. Not to mention the fact that many lounge users are in transit, so no airport check-in there.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "Lounge"? Airline premium passengers lounges? Gate waiting area? The whole departures area post security?

Comment: You can get there quickly (if you are in business class, you have also special lines for check-in, and for security), but queue in to access lounges. As the others commented: it depends: on rush hours you still get queue, and also queue to enter in the lounges.

Comment: Adding to it: for T5 these data would only contain passengers who are flying business or are BA Silver. It would not include First or BA Good as when using First check-in you just walk straight to yhe lounge without separate check in.

Answer (score 2):

Heathrow Terminal 2, 3, 4 and 5 have lounges, so if you are boarding from one of those terminals, just take into consideration the average time you spend for check-in and security (which can reduce considerably if you have boarded online, carry on luggage only, fast-track access via business/1st class/mileage programs, etc.), you should be at your lounge quite quickly after passing security.

Also don't forget boarding starts often 45 minutes prior of departure, so be prepared to leave your lounge on time. Again, if you are a priority passenger, you can afford to arrive to the gate a bit later (like 30 minutes prior to departure).

some useful links:

- [Checking in](https://www.heathrow.com/departures/checking-in)
- [Find a lounge](https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/lounges-hotels-spas)
- [Airport Maps](https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/airport-maps)
- [London Heathrow Airport Lounges: The Complete Guide](https://www.airtravelgenius.com/london-heathrow-airport-lounges/)